I see the 'e-sRGB' color profile listed but from which file it originates?
I see the ICC color profile named e-sRGB (Extended sRGB color encoding; PIMA 7667 2001) listed among the available profiles that can be used in Assign Profile and Convert to Profile in the image editing tool, but I'm unsure which file (icc, icm, or another format) it originates from. Could anyone clarify?
I am using PC Windows.
The e-sRGB does not appear in Control Panel/Color Management/All Profiles.
The e-sRGB or sYCC or PIMA 7667 2001 is mention in:

https://www.imaging.org/IST/IST/Store/StoreLayouts/Item_Detail.aspx?iProductCode=PIMA7667-2001&Category=DOWNLD_PDF
https://www.imaging.org/common/uploaded%20files/pdfs/Papers/2002/PICS-0-267/7111.pdf
https://www.color.org/chardata/rgb/bgsrgb.xalter

But no info about the color profile file or other format that make it appear in the list of color profiles. That is what I need to know.
